# cakephp pagination link with #hash

Tags: cakephp, view, hash, pagination

I have a cakephp view with a paginating helper. I want the pagination link to end with a #hash like this 'http://localhost:8888/uk/brand/sort:name/direction:desc#dist'
I can't find the option to add this in the cakephp 2.0 api.

```
<?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name');?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the third parameter you can specify a url key, which is merged with the pagination url. The router accepts a `#` key, so you could try something like this:

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('name', 'Name', array(
  'url'=> array(
    '#' => 'dist'
  )
));
```